# Running library makefile from application makefile

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I have an application that uses my library. For both projects I have separate makefiles

My application (source code + Makefile) is in 'client' folder. At the same level I have the library folder 'mylib'.

The make file of the client application looks like this:

```
LIBS = -L../mylib -lmy
CFLAGS = -Wall -W -I../mylib

TARGET   = clientapp
SOURCEDIR = .
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath=../mylib
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

Currently to make everything work I need first go to the library folder, call make there, then go to the client application folder and call make here.

What I want to do is to run everything in the client application's makefile.
I found that I need to use 'recursive make'.
But I can't make it build everything. The only library is built.

What is the right syntax for that?

Comment: If you want help you'll have to show us how you invoked the sub-make.  Having the client makefile is useful but without the recursive call we can't really say much.  Also, please provide a more detailed description of what goes wrong.

Comment: Don't.  If you have a library, install it.  Then in your client makefile, link with the installed library.

Comment: @WilliamPursell this is not a 3rd party library. I wouldn't want to install it

Comment: @amplifier If you don't want to install it, then stop calling it a library.  If it's a library, think of it as a distinct project.  If you want it to be a component of one project, don't call it a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although recursive make is not the best solution in the long run, it is a viable option if you are just starting out.

At the top level you just have to create a new Makefile that only executes your two existing makefiles

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    $(MAKE) -C mylib
    $(MAKE) -C source
```

(the indents should be tabs, obviously)

This will execute both makefiles in their respective directories.

It is better to include the makefiles and be non-recursive, but that requires more knowledge of make. Take one step at a time.

Comment: Take a look at [Managing projects with GNU Make](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp) if you want to learn more about make

Comment: Your `-f` options aren't right here: the change dir happens before files are opened so you should use `-f Makefile` or, since that's the default, just leave off the option altogether.

Comment: @MadScientist, the f option is indeed incorrect. Updated the answer.